# Values to the adjusted the bargraph position do not match with each other in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to adjust the order in which the bar plots generated from a loadings graph is shown. Currently, it shows Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, then Petal.Length. I want to see if I can manually adjust the order on the plot by adjusting the plotLoadings() command line (from top to bottom) Petal.Width, Petal.Length, Sepal.Width, and Sepal.Length.

Then, I want to be able to manually change the color of each bar plot, where I can assign blue to Petal.Width and Sepal.Width, and green to Sepal.Length and Petal.Length.

My original code was this here to show the graph before modifications.

```
if(!require(mixOmics)) install.packages("mixOmics", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
suppressWarnings(library (mixOmics, verbose = FALSE))

data(iris)

# Prepare the data
X <- iris[, 1:4]  # Predictor variables
Y <- iris$Species  # Response variable

# Perform PLSDA
plsd <- plsda(X, Y, ncomp = 2)  # Set the number of components as 2

# Plot the loadings
plotLoadings(plsd, comps = 1, main = "PLSDA Loadings")
```

**Edit**
An answer I was able to get help on was able to adjust the order of the variables, **however, now the loading variable "values" or scores, do not match that of the now adjusted variables.** I tried looking into the reason why, but I can't seem to figure why. I suspect that there is a disconnect between the now adjusted rank in the variables vs the values that should be attached to them.

```
library(tidyverse)

plt <- plotLoadings(plsd, comps = 1, main = "PLSDA Loadings")

results <- tibble(col = colnames(X), importance = plt$importance)
            
results %>%
    # the reason the levels are reversed is that coord_flip makes the columns go bottom to top, not top to bottom, so we need to reverse the order of the levels to get the right result
    mutate(col = factor(col, levels = rev(c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Petal.Length")))) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = col, y = importance, fill = col)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
            scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "blue", "green", "blue")) + 
            coord_flip() + 
            theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Any feedback or thoughts on this would be much appreciated please